# Installing Glassfish, Wildfly using homebrew on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, command, glassfish, homebrew

Trying to install **Glassfish**(Java EE App. Server) and **Wildfly App Server**  using **Homebrew** .

http://macappstore.org/wildfly-as/

http://macappstore.org/glassfish/

used these above mentioned tutorials .

I got the following errors while trying to run them by typing just "glassfish" & "wildfly-as" respectively.

**Output(Error):**
-bash: glassfish: command not found

-bash: wildfly-as: command not found

Searched about it and I think it has something to do with $PATH. I don't understand $PATH Variable . Need help.

Comment: What command did you type in that resulted in that error?

Comment: i tried to run them by typing just "glassfish" & "wildfly-as" respectively.

Comment: Try running the command `asadmin start-domain` to start GlassFish. I checked out the [Homebrew install file](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/glassfish.rb) and it looks like it just creates shortcuts for the content's of GlassFish's `bin` directory, so I guess you can just use the normal GlassFish start/stop commands but from any directory.

Comment: And for WildFly you will likely need to follow the instructions Homebrew output about setting `JBOSS_HOME` and appending to your `PATH`, [based on the installation script for that](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/wildfly-as.rb#L18-L25).

Comment: "asadmin start-domain" command returns 

/usr/local/bin/asadmin: line 45: /usr/local/bin/../glassfish/config/asenv.conf: No such file or directory

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that there are two asadmin scripts. One at $GLASSFISH_HOME/bin and one at $GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/bin

Here are full instructions to get your domain up

1. brew update
2. brew install glassfish
3. you should see message, add that line to your .bash_profile

> ```
> ==> Caveats
> You may want to add the following to your .bash_profile:
>
> export GLASSFISH_HOME=/usr/local/opt/glassfish/libexec
> ```

4. Open a new terminal then, cd $GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/bin
5. ./asadmin start-domain --verbose
6. Browse to http://localhost:8080 for welcome page and http://localhost:4848 for admin console

Comment: perfect answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I actually installed Wildfly-Application Server using homebrew but could not find a way to run it.

https://tomylab.wordpress.com/2016/07/03/how-to-install-wildfly-on-mac/

This tutorial helped me .

And for glassfish, my installation was again successful using homebrew but was not able to run it . I did figure it out when I ran the following commands.

```
$  cd /usr/local/opt/glassfish/libexec/bin
$ ./asadmin
asadmin> start-domain
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand about the PATH variable. It is an environment variable on Unix-like operating systems, specifying a set of directories in which executable programs are located. In general, each executing process, or user session, has its own PATH setting.

So, you need to add the glassfish home path to your actual path variable.

Now, as per your problem with running the Glassfish server; try this:

```
export GLASSFISH_HOME=/usr/local/opt/glassfish/libexec/
export PATH=$PATH:$GLASSFISH_HOME/bin
```

Add it to your bash profile, if you do not want to do this everytime.